# Проверка строки регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, шаблоны-проектирования

Правильное  регулярное выражение 
Такая  задача , нужно  проверить строку на соответствие шаблону 
`/avtomobilnaya-elektronika-c361`, 
делаю проверку  таким  способом с помощью выражения,  `/^\/{1}([a-z]){1,}(-){1,}/`:

```
inputTextArray[1].value.search(/^\/{1}([a-z]){1,}(-){1,}/)===-1
```

проблема в том что  в данном выражении не учитываеться -c361 , а нужно что бы  учитывалось , тоесть строки такого формата  `/avtomobilnaya-elektronika` , `/avtomobilnaya-elektronika-`  будут  проходить  проверку ,  а нужно что бы не проходили

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, чему должен соответствовать паттерн: имено приведённой строке и только ей; трём любым группам буквоцифр, разделёных дефисами; любому числу буквоцифр через дефисы? Обязательно ли на конце одна-буква-три-цифры?

Answer (score 2):

Если предположить, что ваша строка должна начинаться с символа `/` и состоять из двух буквенных блоков и одного буквенно-цифрового, разделенных дефисами, то регулярное выражение может выглядеть как-то так:

```
var re = /^\/([a-z]+)\-([a-z]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)$/;

console.log(re.test('/avtomobilnaya-elektronika-c361'));
console.log(re.test('/avtomobilnaya-elektronika-'));
console.log(re.test('/avtomobilnaya-elektronika'));
```

Выведет:

```
true
false
false
```

Comment: может, `/avtomobilnaya-t34-pushka` тоже должна ложиться в паттерн? А вы не допускаете цифр в первых двух блоках. А может, блоков допустимо не только 3 через 2 дефиса. ТС не достаточно чётко сформулировал вопрос пока.

Comment: @Sergiks, я согласен, что постановка вопроса, мягко говоря, расплывчатая. Ждем уточнений от ТС (если они будут).

Comment: @Sergiks, обновил ответ, указав все использованные мной предположения о формате данных.